# aioamqp can't connect to rabbitmqserver

Tags: rabbitmq

The server error is:

[image]

but when I use pika to connect to the rabbitmq server with the same parameter such as same username， password, virtual host, the pika can connect to the server.
the Error code is blow:

> transport, protocol = await aioamqp.connect(host='localhost',
>   virtualhost='/', port=5672, ssl=False, insist=True,
>   login_method='AMQPLAIN')  # use default parameters

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error, and the solution is below:
1\ the master branch code did not correspond to aioamqp pypy code.
2\ so I git clone the master branch code to my project and make some test for it, then id did well for me.